# How to increase speed of execute query in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

The Method `FindByQueryAsNoTracking()` impelemented below:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindByAsNoTracking(Expression<Func<T, bool» predicate)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = Dbset.Where(predicate).AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
        return query;
}
```

if we use `FindByAsQuery` that impelemented below:

```
public IQueryable<T> FindByQuery(Expression<Func<T, bool» predicate)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = Dbset.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
    return query;
}
```

The Speed will get better??

Answer (score 4):

```
AsNoTracking(IQueryable)
```

Returns a new query where the entities returned will **not be cached** in the DbContext or **ObjectContext**. This method works by calling the AsNoTracking method of the underlying query object. If the underlying query object does not have an `AsNoTracking` method, then calling this method will have no effect.

**[No Tracking Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/perf-whitepaper#5-notracking-queries)**

> 5.1 Disabling change tracking to reduce state management overhead If
>   you are in a read-only scenario and want to avoid the overhead of
>   loading the objects into the ObjectStateManager, you can issue "No
>   Tracking" queries.  Change tracking can be disabled at the query
>   level.
>
> Note though that by disabling change tracking you are effectively
>   turning off the object cache. When you query for an entity, we can't
>   skip materialization by pulling the previously-materialized query
>   results from the ObjectStateManager. If you are repeatedly querying
>   for the same entities on the same context, you might actually see a
>   performance benefit from enabling change tracking.
>
> When querying using ObjectContext, ObjectQuery and ObjectSet instances
>   will remember a MergeOption once it is set, and queries that are
>   composed on them will inherit the effective MergeOption of the parent
>   query. When using DbContext, tracking can be disabled by calling the
>   AsNoTracking() modifier on the DbSet.

In short words, yes by using `AsNoTracking` you gain better performance especially when you are going to load lots of data rows but don't forget that it doesn't effect on the SQL generated query, it only increases performance in the `.NET`.

[image: AsNoTracking vs Tracking]

[image]

ps:
Charts are taken from [StaticVoid blog](https://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/entity_framework_and_asnotracking/).

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use Compiled Queries (LINQ to Entities)**

Please refer the [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/compiled-queries-linq-to-entities)

And one more thing if you want child data then set **LazyLoding = true**

default **LazyLoding = true in EntityFramework DBContext class**

**Lazy Loading in Entity Framework**

Lazy loading is delaying the loading of related data until you specifically request for it. It is the opposite of eager loading.
For example, the **Student** entity contains the **StudentAddress** entity. In the lazy loading, the context first loads the **Student** entity data from the **database**, then it will load the **StudentAddress** entity when we access the **StudentAddress** property as shown below.

```
using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
    //Loading students only
    IList<Student> studList = ctx.Students.ToList<Student>();

    Student std = studList[0];

   //Loads Student address for particular Student only (seperate SQL query)
   StudentAddress add = std.StudentAddress;
}
```

The code shown above will result in two SQL queries. First, it will fetch all students:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[StudentID] AS [StudentID], 
[Extent1].[StudentName] AS [StudentName], 
[Extent1].[StandardId] AS [StandardId]
FROM [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent1]
```

Then, it will send the following query when we get the reference of StudentAddress:

```
    exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[StudentID] AS [StudentID], 
[Extent1].[Address1] AS [Address1], 
[Extent1].[Address2] AS [Address2], 
[Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
[Extent1].[State] AS [State]
FROM [dbo].[StudentAddress] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[StudentID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=1
```

**Disable Lazy Loading**

We can disable lazy loading for a particular entity or a context. To turn off lazy loading for a particular property, do not make it virtual. To turn off lazy loading for all entities in the context, set its configuration property to false.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Linq;

public partial class SchoolDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public SchoolDBEntities(): base("name=SchoolDBEntities")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

**Rules for lazy loading:**

- context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled should be true.
- context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled should be true.
- Navigation property should be defined as public, virtual. Context
  will NOT do lazy loading if the property is not defined as virtual.